# Why the below query returns all the records instead of one?

Tags: mysql

I have written below query to fetch the records from DB that matches the id value. But this query return all the records instead of only one record whose id =1.

```
$movie_id=$_GET['id'];   //assume movie_id=1
//$sql ='select * from tbl_movie where movie_id='.$_GET["id"];

$sql='SELECT M.movie_name, MC.on_screen_name, R.role, C.celebrity_name, C.celebrity_id, MI.production, MI.director,'
        . ' MI.screenplay, MI.music, MI.bgm_score, Col.movie_running_time, L.language, CC.censor_certificate,'
        . ' MR.movie_review_comment, A.award_name'
        . ' FROM tbl_movie M INNER JOIN tbl_movie_awards MA INNER JOIN tbl_movie_details MD'
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_cast MC on MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_actor_role R on MC.movie_role_id=R.role_id AND MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_celebrity C on MC.movie_celebrity_id=C.celebrity_id AND MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_awards A on MA.award_id=A.award_id AND MA.award_movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_language L on MD.movie_language_id=L.language_id'
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_censor_certificate CC on MD.censor_id=CC.censor_id AND MD.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_info MI on MI.movie_info_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_collection Col on Col.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_tt_movie_review MR on MR.movie_review_id='.$movie_id.';';

$result = $db->getData($sql);
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
             $movie_name=$row['movie_name'];
        }

    }
```

`getData` function written in another file:

```
public function getData($query)
{
    $result=$this->myconn->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        echo ' error in query execution'.$this->myconn->error;
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is in the above query. Can any one suggest how to get correct answer?

Comment: is your GET value valid? Why have you not escaped it or proofed it from being abused?

Comment: Uh...try adding `WHERE id = 1` ?

Comment: @ Martin, yep, GET value is valid one. now i have typecast that value and assigned to $movie_id = (int) $_GET['id']; Also i am not getting you second question.

Comment: By convention an *INNER* JOIN normally has an ON condition; otherwise it's just a *CROSS* JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the commented line ( //$sql ) at the top is working well, try this:

```
$sql='SELECT M.movie_name, MC.on_screen_name, R.role, C.celebrity_name, C.celebrity_id, MI.production, MI.director,'
        . ' MI.screenplay, MI.music, MI.bgm_score, Col.movie_running_time, L.language, CC.censor_certificate,'
        . ' MR.movie_review_comment, A.award_name'
        . ' FROM tbl_movie M INNER JOIN tbl_movie_awards MA INNER JOIN tbl_movie_details MD'
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_cast MC on MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_actor_role R on MC.movie_role_id=R.role_id AND MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_celebrity C on MC.movie_celebrity_id=C.celebrity_id AND MC.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_awards A on MA.award_id=A.award_id AND MA.award_movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_language L on MD.movie_language_id=L.language_id'
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_censor_certificate CC on MD.censor_id=CC.censor_id AND MD.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_info MI on MI.movie_info_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_collection Col on Col.movie_id='.$movie_id
        . ' INNER JOIN tbl_tt_movie_review MR on MR.movie_review_id='.$movie_id
        . ' WHERE M.movie_id = '.$movie_id.';';
```

You're filtering the tables related with movies (INNER JOIN ... ON id = $movie_id), but the WHERE sentence filters the retrieved result.

EDITED: Actually, I was reviewing your query, and the ON clause after the INNER JOIN is to tell which field is doing the relationship between the tables, without specify the ID, only telling "This table1.ID equals to this table2.ID". Then in the WHERE clause you can add your filtering. So, IMO, the query should be something like this:

```
 $sql='SELECT M.movie_name, MC.on_screen_name, R.role, C.celebrity_name, C.celebrity_id, MI.production, MI.director,'
            . ' MI.screenplay, MI.music, MI.bgm_score, Col.movie_running_time, L.language, CC.censor_certificate,'
            . ' MR.movie_review_comment, A.award_name'
            . ' FROM tbl_movie M '
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_awards MA'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_details MD'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_cast MC ON MC.movie_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_actor_role R ON MC.movie_role_id = R.role_id AND MC.movie_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_celebrity C ON MC.movie_celebrity_id = C.celebrity_id AND MC.movie_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_awards A ON MA.award_id = A.award_id AND MA.award_movie_id = M.movie_id
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_language L ON MD.movie_language_id = L.language_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_censor_certificate CC ON MD.censor_id = CC.censor_id AND MD.movie_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_info MI ON MI.movie_info_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_movie_collection Col ON Col.movie_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' INNER JOIN tbl_tt_movie_review MR ON MR.movie_review_id = M.movie_id'
            . ' WHERE M.movie_id = '.$movie_id.';';
```

Comment: after adding WHERE condition into query, it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad to help you ;)
Check the edited answer if you want, I think you shouldn't use the ON clause to filter, at least in your case.